# Why does this VBA Loop to find empty cell delete header row value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where each branch office has it's own tab. Each tab has row headers of available dates for interviews, and the column headers for the available times. It is screencapped below:

[image]

From there I'm using a user form to collect the branch name from a dropdown (populated by looping through names of the sheets), the available dates (getting the days on the identified sheet), then the blank times for the given dates.

For some reason, every time a date is selected, it's setting the date cell to "" or blank. Can anyone verify my syntax if right? I can't tell where it might be setting it to blank... Thanks!

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()Dim sht As Worksheet
    'clear form
    BranchBox.Value = ""
    DateBox.Value = ""
    TimeBox.Value = ""

    'populate sheet names from each branch
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      Me.BranchBox.AddItem sht.Name
    Next sht
End Sub
Public Sub BranchBox_Change()
    'populate dates
    Me.DateBox.List = Worksheets(BranchBox.Value).Range("A2:A31").Value
End Sub
Public Sub DateBox_Change()
    Dim dateSel As String
    Dim branch As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim matchingHeader As Range

    branch = BranchBox.Value
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(branch)
    dateSel = DateBox.Value

    'Get Row to scan
    Dim i As Long, rowOff As Long
    For i = 2 To sht.Rows.Count
        Set cel = sht.Cells(i, 1)
        If cel.Value = dateSel Then
            rowOff = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'Scan selected row for blank cells
    Dim cnt As Integer
    For i = 2 To sht.Columns.Count
        cel = sht.Cells(rowOff, i)
        If CStr(cel.Value) = "" Then
            Set matchingHeader = sht.Cells(1, i)
            TimeBox.AddItem matchingHeader.Value
        End If
    Next i

    Me.TimeBox.AddItem ("No Appointments Available")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
cel = sht.Cells(rowOff, i)
```

is implicitly

```
cel.Value = sht.Cells(rowOff, i).Value
```

I believe you intended the line to be

```
Set cel = sht.Cells(rowOff, i)
```

Comment: That took care of it! Thanks!